# No more events, simulation completed -- at t=0s, event #0 ** Calling finish() methods of modules

Tags: omnet++

When I run the program, it directly appears:

> No more events, simulation completed -- at t=0s, event #0
> ** Calling finish() methods of modules

Instead of initializing and sending self messages as I thought, I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow! The message means that all planned events have been done. Probably you do not schedule the selfmessage. Could you edit your question and provide [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your network really contains the simple modules you assume you are running and also that they are correctly linked in. Make sure also that the initialization() call is indeed correctly inserts your events.